# Setting up the Raspberry as a data logger

Tags: power, filesystem, mount, lxde

As the title states I'm working on a simple embedded application which reads some information from the serial port and logs it to file, in addition to displaying a bit of status on the display.

I'm now at the stage the logging seems to be running and I'm trying to configure the system and I've got a couple of questions.

1. The system is intended to log data to a FAT32 USB stick, which may be unplugged, replugged or replaced at any time. What is the preferred method of auto-mounting any inserted USB mass storage into a fixed directory? The usbmount package seems to nearly do this but the lack of maintenance makes bit wary.
2. I cannot guarantee the power supply and perform clean shut-downs. Thankfully the only files to be written, aside from internal OS information, should be the logs. Will a journalling file system for the OS save me from myself or should I be mounting the system read-only or tinkering with RAM disks?
3. Will the FAT file system on the USB stick survive and recover from power outages and sudden ejections? Should I create a new log file each time it gets mounted?
4. I've set up the X server to start automatically and fiddled with the LXDE autostart scripts to start the status display and disable the window manager/screen saver. Are there any other gotchas to maintaining a continuous display?
5. The logger will not have Ethernet access and rather needs an accurate clock. Is the RasClock module a suitable option?

Sorry about the long post and multiple semi-related questions.

I'm used to dealing with simple embedded devices for which I have full control over the software, and the task of correctly configuring a real operating system is making me a bit anxious.
On the other hand I rather suspect that I'm not the only one (ab-)using the Pi for this type of application so hopefully the questions are not too specific to my particular situation.

Comment: Are you describing your working USB->serial solution somewhere so other would-be dataloggers can try it? I'm keen to get some additional value out of my scraper/logger/webcam Pi. Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> The system is intended to log data to a FAT32 USB stick, which may be unplugged, replugged or replaced at any time.

The *unplugged* part of that is problematic. AFAIK, no computer system anywhere promises you the right to yank a USB stick out unannounced at any point without potential problems.  So you will have to think about how to get around that.

> I cannot guarantee the power supply and perform clean shut-downs.

Again, suddenly cutting the power on (just about) any computer system is risky.  It *usually* ends up okay (who hasn't done this a bunch of times, by accident, due to power failure, etc?), **but** there seems to be an unusual amount of people reporting SD card corruption with the pi.  So if you mean, "Mostly the system will not be shut down cleanly" you need to rethink, because that will be a dead end strategy.  Note that it is possible to [trigger a shutdown](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/4719/how-to-shut-down-rpi-when-running-headless/4722#4722) without a keyboard or network connection.  You could use a similiar method to trigger a clean unmounting of the usb stick too.

You can add the `sync` option in `/etc/fstab` to restrict caching, but `man mount` notes:

> In case of
>   media with limited number of write cycles (e.g. some flash drives)
>   "sync" may cause
>                 life-cycle shortening.

This includes SD cards, although as long as you remember to intermittently test (and replace, when appropriate) your media it may be worth while.  This will  impact general performance slightly, I think.

So, try to avoid yanking the plug or usb stick suddenly as best you can, and certainly don't design a setup that depends on this.  Eg, don't tell yourself or other users, "It is okay to unplug the USB stick whenever you want", because it isn't and you can't make it so.

Making appropriate `sync` calls in your application (eg, when idle, or after a significant write) is a good idea.

Once you have **everything you want installed and configured**, you can potentially mount the root filesystem read-only, if you create separate partitions for `/var`, `/run`, and `/tmp` and mount those rw;  you could also create one such mounted partition and symlink the rw directories into it.

On a raspbian pi, you don't have to worry about `/run`, as it is tmpfs (RAM) already; `/sys` and `/proc` are also in RAM (but don't use them for anything except what they are intended).  If the system is for a single purpose and all your data goes to the USB stick, `/var` is the only problematic one but not, I think, critically so.

Comment: Our primary problem is that the power may cut out at any time during an emergency stop, something I suspect will be a frequent occurrence during testing (hence the need for a logger to begin with).

I will check we might tack on a back-up battery for the Pi, and perhaps wire up some sort of sensor to detect loss of power.

However my life would be a lot easier if the root file system might be mounted in read-only mode and the USB memory guarded through periodic flushes and the like.

Comment: @doynax : It is possible to run the with the root filesystem RO.  I don't have any experience with that, but I added a couple of paragraphs at the end about what I believe the basic concerns are.

Answer (score 2):

In a former life I worked on device drivers that read/wrote memory cards.
They could be yanked in the middle of any operation, so even battery or 
capacitor backed up power wouldn't help.  Based on the formatting 
specs of the chips, I inferred the behavior required to have minimum
damage done by "hot" removal and insertion.

Basically, what you need to do is ensure that if you are cut off mid-write
of a data block (or the contacts are squirrely) you can recognize the fact.
basically prepend the data with a block number (and length if not fixed size),
and append a crc and (the same) block number at the end.

The first write you do is at the end, with a value that is NOT the next block
number.  This way, if your write doesn't complete, there will be a block
number mismatch and that data block is known to be garbage.  Then write your
data block with the real block number, followed by the length, followed by your
CRC generated by your favorite algorithm, and the real block number again.  (The
 CRC is to protect against squirrely contacts that corrupt your data).

When power is restored or the memory card re-inserted, only accept sequential
blocks to the point the block begin and end sequence numbers don't match or 
the CRC is incorrect.  Remove that block and resume logging.

This is low level stuff though. Doing it through a file system is another story.

What you really need is redundant copies of your FAT, and do a similar
thing around the FAT table.   The sequential number will tell you which is most 
recent, and the front/back match and CRC will ensure the integrity.

It's past my bedtime so I hope this is clear enough.

Answer (score 1):

As for the accurate clock, there are lots of cheap GPS modules available.  Hard to find a more accurate clock than that.

Comment: That's an excellent suggestion. Save us the trouble of setting the clock and dealing with the battery. We'll just need to keep track of the time-zone (and DST rules I suppose), and for a pure data logger universal time should be fine.

Comment: Does a GPS module work indoor when no part of the sky is visible and still provide a benefit over a simple RTC ?