# Shutting down my Pi safely

Tags: headless, power-management

I was looking at [How to shut down RPi when running headless](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/4719/how-to-shut-down-rpi-when-running-headless) and really happy to see the awesomeness!

So, is it possible to use udev rule to shutdown my Pi when I switch off the router that connects my Pi with the eth cable?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could write a script that checks the content of the file `/sys/class/net/eth0/operstate` in a loop. When the state shows `down` execute the `halt` command on your RPi.

Something like:

```
while true
    grep 'down' /sys/class/net/eth0/operstate && halt
    sleep 5
done
```

Or, even better with a cron job run, say, every 2 minutes:

```
*/2 * * * * root /bin/grep 'down' /sys/class/net/eth0/operstate && halt -p
```

Comment: Great one! The cron will be better, I think.

Comment: The cron job was not running with the entry that you provided. It seems, you missed the user name in the crontab entry. I added root as the user and added -p to power down when it halts.