# Run a command when wifi adapter is disconnected?

Tags: usb, wifi, wireless-adapter

Is there any way to detect when a USB Wi-Fi adapter is physically disconnected from the Pi, and run a command when that happens? I'm using the Raspberry Pi 1, model B+, and the adapter is connected to the bottom right USB port. It's the Ralink RT5370 adapter, if it helps.

Comment: If you mean *physically disconnected*, as in pulled out, yes -- you want to look into **udev** rules.  For an  example demonstrating how to shut the pi down cleanly when a particular device is removed see here: http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/4722/5538 (you could do anything that way, not just run `shutdown`). If you mean "disconnected from the network" also yes, but the methodology would be unrelated.

Answer (score 3):

Assuming you don't have any network equipment other that the WIFI dongle that you could unplug, you could simply write

```
SUBSYSTEM=="net", ACTION=="remove", RUN+="/path/to/command"
```

into a file named `/etc/udev/rules.d/my_custom.rules`. Note that you need to specify the full path to your command, since it will be executed directly, without using a shell.